# R ggplot2: Bar chart for the answers on the question with multiple response option

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a bar chart for the answers on the question with multiple response option. The code works but the graph shows additional column without the title. Where does this column come from and how can I remove it? Is it somehow related to NA?

This is the code:

```
Q10 <- ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Q10a, fill = Time),
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Q10b, fill = Time),
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Q10c, fill = Time),
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Q10d, fill = Time),
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Q10e, fill = Time),
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 90))
Q10
```

This is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7RHF.png)

Comment: Wild guess: First if not organize your data in long format (for example with `pivot_longer()`), then all Q10a to 10e should be in one column. If this is true, it seems that you have some NA in this column, lets call this column `Qcolumn`. If so you can do: `ggplot(df %>% 
         filter(!is.na(Qcolumn)), aes(x=Qcolumn)) +
  geom_bar()`

Comment: Please add the output of `dput(df)` to your question. This will make it much easier to diagnose this issue and provide a working solution.

Comment: Result of dput(df) has too many characters for posting.

Comment: You should probably be using geom_col().  You don't really want a bar chart.